# Is ssh public key associated with a user?

Tags: ssh

My guess is that a machine running `ssh server` keeps a mapping of a `ssh public key` to my user name (I am a remote user) who has authorized access.
But a few other people and I are also able to login on behalf of some local user to the remote machine (meaning that we have a remote machine with a local user `john.doe` to that machine). Does it mean that there is also a mapping of a user `john.doe` to a multiple `ssh public keys` who are authorized to access on behalf of `john.doe`?

Comment: Considering you can change keys at anytime, no.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Sample scenario: you (Bob) want to connect to remote host (`earth`) as `alice`.

SSH is a connection from someplace (a Unix, Windows, tablet, ...) to a user (`alice`) on a host (`earth`).

When you (`bob`) connect without password, you use a private key (on Unix it is traditionally located in `~/.ssh`, but you can put it anywhere).

The remote host just have two facts:

- you want to connect as `alice`,
- you claim to have a private key (of which you provided the fingerprint)

The remote host (`earth`), having public part of the key, issues a challenge that anyone having private part can answer. Once challenge is done, you simply connect.

In this scenario, you proved you have private part of one of `alice`'s authorized keys. But the remote host (`earth`) has no way to know you are Bob, or Igor or anyone else.

Remember you can connect from Windows or an Android device where user's scheme is completely different.

## `authorized_keys`

This file lists public keys that can connect (after challenge).

This file is located either in

- `${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys` (default)
- any location given by  `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `sshd_config` file. See `man sshd_config`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats's becoming much clearer now. Unfortunately my user dir on a remote machine does not have ``.ssh`` dir. So, I tried to look into ``sshd_config`` in ``/etc/ssh`` but unfortunately I don't have permissions. My guess that it has something like ``john.doe -> list of authorized keys``. Is that correct?

Comment: “No”??? What? The short answer is yet, and the longer answer is `authorized_keys`.

Comment: No: ssh keys isn't associate with a **remote** user. (but is with a local user)

Answer (score 4):

I don't fully understand your question, but the way a SSH key is mapped to user `johndoe` (and authorizes him to log in passwordlessly to the remote server) is that the public key part is included in the file

```
~johndoe/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

on the remote server.

If now you have the private key part on your `~/.ssh/` directory (that'll be the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), you can login passwordlessly on the remote server via the command:

```
ssh johndoe@remoteserver
```

regardless of your username on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

yes, a private key can be linked to one or more users using authorized_keys file.

In order for your linux server to recognize and accept your key pair, you will need to upload your public key to your server. More specifically, you will need to upload your public key to the home directory of the user you would like to log in as. If you would like to log in to more than one user on the server using your key pair, you will need to add your public key to each of those users.

To set up SSH key authentication for one of your server’s users, add your public key to a new line inside the user’s authorized_keys file. This file is stored inside a directory named .ssh/ under the user’s home folder. A user’s authorized_keys file can store more than one public key, and each public key is listed on its own line. If your file contains more than one public key, then the owner of each key listed will be able to log in as that user.

Source: https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/